# Graph api, cannot change password through /me/changePassword resource

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to change user's password with the following resource:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-changepassword?msclkid=9549af45bca611ecbef12e519c4fdf2c&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

The user is previously created with invitations resource:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

The access token has permission: Directory.AccessAsUser.All.

The code goes as follows:

```
graphClient().me()
                .changePassword(UserChangePasswordParameterSet
                        .newBuilder()
                        .withCurrentPassword(currentPassword)
                        .withNewPassword(newPassword)
                        .build())
                .buildRequest()
                .post()
```

I get the error:

```
"Incorrect password. Password provided does not match the 
old password. paramName: oldPassword, paramValue: , objectType: System.String"
```

I get the same error when requesting api directly by http.

I'm sure the current password is correct.

Changing password works if users's passwordProfile is previously updated with resource:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-update-the-passwordprofile-of-a-user-to-reset-their-password

Why a user can't change password after accepting the invitation?

Comment: Have you tried checking in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge)?

Comment: I can't check it due to Authentication failed error

Comment: Which means that the password you are typing should be wrong. Please resent your password and try again.

Comment: The password is correct. I can login with it to my app. The error is visible only in Graph explorer, above Response preview. Can it be connected with the fact that user is a Guest user?

Comment: Yes it could be. In the [Note section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) it says it should be tied to an AAD tenant.

Comment: Guest users are tied to my tenant, they have properly generated upn.

Comment: One last thing you can try is giving a role to your user. Try giving Global admin role once and see if it includes the permission.

Comment: I have no error about lack of permissions. Changing password by admin account sometimes works, but it's random behaviour.